# How to count distinct values over two categories?

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I have a SQL query that shows me the clients and product for each purchase

```
client    | product
-----------------------
Lucy Lu   | Banana
Lucy Lu   | Banana
Lucy Lu   | Pineapple    
Mad Damon | Banana
Mad Damon | Apple
Mad Damon | Apple
Peter Fox | Banana
Peter Fox | Banana
Peter Fox | Banana
Peter Fox | Apple    
Peter Fox | Apple
```

I want to distinct these query but the count of each product for each customer, so I can see for each customer how much of each product he bought:

```
client    | product   | count
----------------------------
Lucy Lu   | Banana    | 2
Lucy Lu   | Pineapple | 1
Mad Damon | Banana    | 1
Mad Damon | Apple     | 2
Peter Fox | Banana    | 3
Peter Fox | Apple     | 2
```

I tried it with `count(DISTINCT product)`, `count(DISTINCT client)`, `count(*)` and `GROUP BY (client)` or `GROUP BY (product)`, but didn't get a useful solution. 
When I try it with `SELECT DISTINCT` [rest of the query], I get what I want but without the count column.

Comment: `select client   , product, count(*) from t group by client   , product`

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use DISTINCT. A simple GROUP BY with COUNT will do the trick.

Oto Shavadze suggested this query:

```
select client, product, count(*) 
from t 
group by client, product;
```

Here you make groups based on the distinct values of (client, product) pairs. The COUNT will give you the count of rows in each of these group.

Comment: If @Oto Shavadze posts his comment as an answer, I'm ready to delete mine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was ist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query and you will get the output.
Here test_data is the table name. Please replace it with your table_name.

```
SELECT count(product) as count,client, product from test_data group by product,client
```